# twig sort not working in this situation

Tags: twig

sort does not work here

```
{% for key, season in seasons | sort %}
```

but does here

```
{% for episode in season | sort %}
```

here is the entire twig snippet

```
{% for key, season in seasons | sort %}  {# <<this is the sort not working #}
    <button class="accordion"><h5>Season {{ key }}</h5></button>
    <div class="panel">
    {% for episode in season | sort %}
        <li><h5><b>{{ episode.title }}</b></h5></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Do you have a sample of what is contained in some elements of the arrays?

Comment: Seems it does do the same thing. Watch [here](https://twigfiddle.com/t53qll)

Answer (score 0):

If you need reverse sort use this.

```
{% for key, season in seasons |sort((a, b) => a.id <= b.id) %} 
  {% for episode in season | sort %}
    {{ episode.title }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

You juste need add in your for this code.

```
|sort((a, b) => a.id <= b.id)
```